# Can I see my connection strength/ping to other players in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Is there anyway to see how good my connection strength or my ping is compared to other players in a multiplayer game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, which is a pretty annoying issue and will hopefully be added soon

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this feature is unavailble at this time. You can, however, file a feature request at [the BioWare Forums](http://social.bioware.com), where the developers will see it and take the idea into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has made a third-party tool to do this called "Host Locator/Ping Utility". I haven't tried it myself, but just putting it out there.

The official thread for it is no longer accessible, but the you can see [an archived version at the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731203305/https://forum.bioware.com/topic/355406-in-game-pinglocator-utility-pc-v111).

Someone's made [a re-post of it on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MECoOp/comments/1iykww/host_locatorpingutility/) with at least one possibly-working download link.